# Will Microsoft Graph API work if office graph is disabled for the Office 365 tenant?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a list of endpoints that will work and wont work when the Office Graph is disabled in Office 365 Tenant ?

Answer (score 0):

The endpoints that will not work are /trendingAround and /workingWith, you will get empty results.
All other request are not impacted.